# DbUnit H2 in memory db with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, h2, dbunit

Hi I'm trying a little POC with JPA and unit test to verify that the DB schema is created. I'm working with H2 DB and I set to Hibernate create the schema from the entities, but when DbUnit tries to initialize the DB from a dataset I always get a Table ... not found in tableMap. I read that I have to add the property DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to DB URL but is like after Hibernate creates the schema the DB is losted when DbUnit tries to initialize.

Any ideas? Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my config:

**application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceH2" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <!-- property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" /-->
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <!-- property name="database" value="MYSQL" /-->
        </bean>    
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">CALLBACK</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSourceH2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

**RepositoryTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/application-context-test.xml" })
@Transactional
public class SystemEntityRepositoryH2Test {

    @Inject
    private SystemEntityRepository repository;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSourceH2;

    private IDatabaseConnection connection;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbUnitCon = null;
        dbUnitCon = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSourceH2, "testdb");
        dbUnitCon.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

        IDataSet dataSet = this.getDataSet("dataset-systementity.xml");
        DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(dbUnitCon, dataSet);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(this.getConnection(), this.getDataSet(dataSetFile));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

    }

    protected IDataSet getDataSet(String dataSetFile) throws Exception {
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new ClassRelativeResourceLoader(this.getClass());
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(dataSetFile);

        if (resource.exists()) {
            return new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(resource.getInputStream());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**dataset-systementity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <System_Entities id="2" name="NAME" phone01="+52-55-55555555" email="a@a.com"
                    address01="Street" address02="123" address03="1" address04="Address04"
                    address05="Address05" city="City" state="State" country="MX"
                    zipcode="12345" />
</dataset>
```

**Error**

```
ERROR DatabaseDataSet:286 - Table 'System_Entities' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap[_tableNames=[], _tableMap={}, _caseSensitiveTableNames=false]
```

I can see that the tables are created by hibernate because the log shows all the sql sentences without error.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks Mark Robinson
I modified the setUp method to:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbUnitCon = null;
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        SessionImplementor si = (SessionImplementor) session;
        Connection conn = si.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
        dbUnitCon = new DatabaseConnection(conn);

        //dbUnitCon.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES, true);

        IDataSet dataSet = this.getDataSet("dataset-systementity.xml");
        DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(dbUnitCon, dataSet);
    }
```

It works now, what I don't understand yet is if I use HSQLDB I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that DBUnit is loading the table data before Hibernate can initialize.

As part of your `@setup`, you'll need to get the Hibernate session.  This should cause Hibernate to create your table.  You could even force it by executing a simple query like `select 1`

Comment: Thanks! the problem now is in my test method, I save an object using a repository object and after that I want to get the actual dataSet using createDataSet() from the dbUnitCon but I get a "Timeout trying to lock table..." error, I added MVCC=TRUE to the connection url and it works but the dataset only includes the data that dbunit initializes, it does not include the object saved with the repository object.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, it's like the transaction used by the repository is not committed yet and when I try to get the actual dataset I can't see that change, I don't know where to go after this.